# Incorrect special character on textview in android

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, inputstream

I am trying to display a simple `ñ` (Special spanish) character on the Textview but instead of `ñ` it is displaying some junk character `�`. I have try many SOV solutions but didn't work for me.`ñ` is coming from SOAP web service.

Below is the code:

```
 InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
 SoapObject soapObject=Utility.InToSoapObject(in);

public static SoapObject InToSoapObject(InputStream inputStream) {
        SoapObject soap = null;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        try {
            XmlPullParser p = Xml.newPullParser();
            p.setInput(inputStream, "utf-8");
            envelope.parse(p);
            soap = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return soap;
    }
```

Few things that I have tried so far but  didn't work for me

1. Replacing `ñ` with \u0148
2. (Html.fromHtml(str)
3. URLEncoder.encode(str)
4. Replace UTF-8 with iso-8859-1

I am extracting String character from SOAP in correct manner that I have cross checked. May be there is some issue with `UTF-8`. Any  kind of help or suggestions will be appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have two accounts in SO? The same question you asked [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972595/android-textview-displaying-wrong-character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972595/android-textview-displaying-wrong-character)

Comment: Yes but hardly used that one. By mistake I have post the question there .. I  used this account frequently..I have already delete the question from there. I think that is not an issue..

Comment: Can you help me out in figuring the solution of the above question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was extracting the String output from a webservice but when I replaced UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, it got resolved. What I used was the following,

Converted the InputStream to BufferedReader using the ISO_8859-1 format and handled the resultant BufferedReader to convert as String.

```
private String getResponseString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"ISO-8859-1"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    finally {
        stream.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I have try this way too but didn't work for me. Still I'll give a look to this solution again..anyway tnx

Comment: It worked for me. I really had huge trouble by converting each of special characters with encoding values (as like you mentioned replacing ñ with \u0148). Finally found this solution some where and it did work. I posted the code which I'm using it all long these days. Hope it should work for you too. If so accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
String  = URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: now instead of � am getting  "%EF%BF%BD" ..looking for ñ character..any  other soln